# casting a dereference Char iterator to int C++

Tags: c++, vector, casting, iterator

I have a vector of chars it contains 252 characters in total. I'm trying to filter out the words, operators and numbers putting them into their own vectors.

I used an iterator to move through the vector of chars. The issue I've run into is putting the numbers (which are all integers) into a vector of integers.

I tried casting the dereferenced iterator to an `int` but it still stores the decimal representation instead of the `char` (48 for 0, 49 for 1 ect). I can use the  code I have in which I subtract `48` from all the entries. I guess I'm just wondering if there's a better way or if this is "good practice"

```
if(isdigit(*it)){
        int a = (int)*it;
        NumList.push_back(a-48);
        advance(it,1);
}
```

`it` is the iterator I used to traverse the vector of chars. `NumList` is a vector made to hold all the numbers I find. Originally I just tried `push_back(*it)` that clearly didn't work. I've tried casting `*it` to an `int` in all the ways I know that work with normal variables.

Is there a method to use or something. I just can't find one here or at Cplusplusorg.

P.S.: Sorry if this is basic I'm just not very familiar with iterators. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `48` is certainly not a good way to write `'0'`, but `a - '0'` would be a perfectly good way to do it.

Comment: (int)*it is the number of the character (in ASCII code) representing a digit, so you really have to subtract 48, or better '0' as the previous comment says, to get the numeric value of the digit. I don't think that there is a "better" way.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you're asking about the implementation of a function of the form

```
inline int char_to_pos(char c)
```

As @n.m pointed out correctly, a good way to do this would be

```
inline int char_to_pos(char c)
{
    return c - '0';
}
```

Since there is a very small number of distinct chars (256), you could possibly make this a bit faster by preprocessing. First create a vector of ints, and place, at each position, the position subtracted by `'0'`. This should be done before all calls to `char_to_pos`. Following that, `char_to_pos`, when given `c`, would simply retun `pos[c]` (assuming the vector is `pos`).

In this case, since you're performing a `push_back` on the results, it not might be very consequential, though.